# layered costmaps map_topic

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning to use layered costmaps, have gone through the tutorials, and they are basically working.
However, I don't understand how map_topics works with map_server.  I suspect I am missing some very basic point, but need help to figure it out.

I can specify a map_topic associated with a static layer (see below), but I don't know how to publish a map to that map_topic.  As far as I can tell, map_server only publishes to /map.

For example, I have two static maps, one for a lower laser  and the other for an upper laser.
I setup the local costmap params as follows, but cannot get map_server to supply the maps with specific topic names.

Also, in amcl, I want to only use the upper static map.  I know that I can make the parameter "use_map_topic" = true, but how do I specify the map_topic name?

```
lower_costmap:
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
   update_frequency: 1.0
   publish_frequency: 0.0
   static_map: true
   rolling_window: false
   resolution: 0.05
   transform_tolerance: 1.0

   plugins:
       - {name: static_map_10lx_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
       - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
       - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

and the global as follows:

```
upper_costmap:
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
   update_frequency: 1.0
   publish_frequency: 0.0
   static_map: true
   rolling_window: false
   resolution: 0.05
   transform_tolerance: 1.0

   plugins:
       - {name: static_map_30lx_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
       - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
       - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

with the common params as follows:

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[0.23, 0.23], [0.23, -0.23], [-0.23, -0.23], [-0.23, 0.23]]
#robot_radius: 0.4
inflation_radius: 0.34
max_obstacle_height: 0.6
min_obstacle_height: 0.0

static_map_30lx_layer:
    map_topic: /30lx

static_map_10lx_layer:
    map_topic: /10lx

obstacle_layer:
    observation_sources: hokuyo_04lx
    hokuyo_04lx: {sensor_frame: hokuyo_04lx_link, data_type: LaserScan, obstacle_range: 8, topic: /hokuyo_04lx_scan, marking: true, clearing: true}

inflation_layer:
    inflation_radius: 0.34
```

In a launch file, I run map_server as follows:

```
<arg name="map_name" value="30lx"/>
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find myBot)/maps/$(arg map_name).yaml">
    <param name="frame_id" value="hokuyo_30lx_link"/>
</node>
```

but there is no way I can find to publish to the map_topic.  Assuming that I do find a way to do that, should I run two instances of map_server, each publishing its own topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195289/layered-costmaps-map_topic/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2014-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The static layer has a `map_topic` parameter that can be set to set the static map topic name. See: http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/staticmap

For the map server and AMCL, you can use [topic remapping arguments](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) or the [roslaunch remap tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) to change the topic name.

EDIT:

If you're looking to publish maps dynamically (perhaps changing floors or buildings), the [map_store](http://wiki.ros.org/map_store) may also be useful, but it's not documented.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2014-10-19**:
I am using the map_topic parameter in the static layer (see the common params above).
I have used topic remapping, but didn't think it would work here. Can I just  in the map_server launch file?  With amcl, what is the parameter to set when I have "use_map_topic" = true

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-19**:
Yeah, the remapping arguments should work for the map_server node as well. Also note that remapping affects services as well as topics, so you can remap the `static_map` service as well. It looks like AMCL uses the same `~use_map_topic` parameter: http://wiki.ros.org/amcl?distro=indigo

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2014-10-19**:
I think that means I can leave amcl "use_map_topic" = false and just remap "static_map" to "30lx" in both map_server and amcl, is that right?
Thanks for the help!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-19**:
Yep, that sounds correct!